# Total Sum of Column after input calculation in rows Javascript

Tags: javascript, sum

First of, I would like to say Thank you to those who started this field- Web Development. It is awesome especially coding. I think it is cool. Well, I am civil engineer by profession but does coding as my hobby free time. Now I got into seriousness and thought to improve my productivity in work as well as my team.

I have developed the table. I got the answer for calculating the "Amount" on the 7th column by multiplying the inputs of column 5 & 6 which is awesome (Sorry, I get too excited when i find the solution).

But where got stuck is the (got me frustrated! despite trying numerous times and finding other solutions or methods- this is what i got close to)- Total Sum of 7th column and 3rd Row. Total says 'Nan' which is odd. I am sure, i got somewhere wrong. I am unable to get the Total Sum of the rows in the Amount column.

Thank you for your patience in reading my question. Your help/comment/suggestions would be much appreciated. Any improvements are most welcome.

Please visit my fiddle site https://jsfiddle.net/sandz/bxj38zps/1/  which leads to the code that I had developed. or have a look below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>TABLE RETEST</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="w3-container w3-padding-4x w3-indigo">
        <h2>
          Table Testing
        </h2>
    </div>

    <div class="w3-container w3-section w3-pale-green">
    <table class="w3-table-all" id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
        <tr class="titlerow">
            <th>SN</th>
            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
            <TH>UNIT</TH>
            <TH>REQD QTY</TH>
            <TH>AVAIL. QTY</TH>
            <TH>RATE</TH>
            <TH>AMOUNT</TH>
            <TH>REMARKS IF ANY</TH>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Steel</td>
            <td>Ton</td>
            <td>200</td>
            <td><input id="a.qty" type="number" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
            <td><input id="rate" type="number" oninput="calculate()" /></td>
            <td class="rowDataSd"><input id="amt1" type="number" name="amount" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Cement</td>
            <td>Bags</td>
            <td>300</td>
            <td><input id="qty2" type="number" oninput="calculate1()" /></td>
            <td><input id="rate2" type="number" oninput="calculate1()" /></td>
            <td class="rowDataSd"><input id="amt2" type="number" name="amount" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="totalColumn">
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="totalCol"><input type="button" onclick="Calculate()" value="calculate"> TOTAL:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name=""></td>
        </tr>

    </table>



    <script>
        function calculate(){
            var x1 = document.getElementById('a.qty').value;
            var x2 = document.getElementById('rate').value;
            var x3 = document.getElementById('amt1').value;
            var x4 = x1 * x2;
            amt1.value = x4;
        }

        function calculate1() {
            var y1 = document.getElementById('qty2').value;
            var y2 = document.getElementById('rate2').value;
            var y3 = document.getElementById('amt2').value;
            var y4 = y1 * y2;
            amt2.value = y4;

        }

                            var totals = [0];

            $(document).ready(function() {

            var $dataRows = $("#sum_table tr:not('.totalColumn, .titlerow')");

             $dataRows.each(function() {
            $(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i) {
             totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
                });
            });
            $("#sum_table td.totalCol").each(function(i) {
            $(this).html("total:" + totals[i]);
             });

            });

        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because in

```
$(this).find('.rowDataSd').each(function(i) {
  totals[i] += parseInt($(this).html());
});
```

`$(this).html()` will return the input-field in the table cell and not the value within the input-field. Modify this bit to iterate over the input fields and get their value.

```js
// ".rowDataSd input" selects all inputs within elements that have class="rowDataSd"
$(this).find('.rowDataSd input').each(function(i) {
  // So "this" is now an input, so we can $(this).val() to get its value.
  // And in case there is no value, parseInt will return NaN, so we default to 0 in this case
  totals[i] += parseInt($(this).val()) || 0;
});
```

Comment: thank you spotting this out Moxn. I got the point. Could you please elaborate it more. JSFiddle or Anything like that Perhaps, If you dont mind ?. Thats because, I am take a bit longer to understand until I see examples. Much Appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Rookie_Coder, I have added some comments to explain changes. Have fun

Comment: @Rookie_Coder, if this answers your question you can mark this answer as accepted. Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for more information. And welcome to SO